# Searching specified row and return column in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to search the columns of a datafame on a specific row number to find an after finding the column, return another row value of the same column. In the following example, the selected row number is 2 and the value to search is 5, known as key. It will match the third column, V2. Then I want to return the third row value of V2.

```
V0,V1,V2,V3
4,1,1,1
6,4,5,2
2,3,6,7
```

In the following code, I first extract the specified `row`, then iterate over that like an array to find the index of the match and the, use the found index to access the original datafram column.

```
key = 5
row = df.iloc[1]              # row=[6,4,5,2]
for i in range(len(row)):
    if row[i] == key:
        res = df.iloc[:,i]    # i=2, res=[1,5,6]
        print(res[2])
```

output is 6. Is there any better to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing the `eq` (equal) follow by the `shift` slice

```
df.shift(-1)[df.eq(5)].stack().iloc[0]
Out[542]: 6.0
```

More detail : notice the first level index ,should always +1 refer to the original df

```
df.shift(-1)[df.eq(5)].stack()
Out[543]: 
1  V2    6.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Can you explain more about that first level index? If the index of [V2,6.0] is 1, what is there fore index 0?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using numpy's argwhere function which finds the matching index of interest.

```
import numpy as np

key = 5
row = 2

# use numpy argwhere function to identify the index
indices = np.argwhere(df.values[row, :] == key).flatten()

# use indices as input to DataFrame.iloc
df.iloc[row+1, indices]
```